# iOS view appears before animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

I'm trying to maintain existing code and added a new `UITextView` to a `View Controller`. All of the views enter the screen by sliding in from the left side. My newly added view also slides in from the left side along with the other views (without me doing anything because the animation is set on their container). The problem is that **my view also appears for a second or so before the animation starts**. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the code for the animation on the container

```
- (void) showAndAnimateContainerView{
[self.containerView setHidden:NO];
[self hideContainerView:self.containerView];
self.marginLeft.constant = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:STD_ANIMATION_TIME delay:ZERO_ANIMATION_TIME options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
}

- (void) hideContainerView:(UIView *) view{
self.widthView.constant = WIDTH_SCREEN;
self.marginLeft.constant = -WIDTH_SCREEN;
[view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Don't know what else I can add to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: are you using autolayout for your added textview ?

Comment: Yes I am using autolayout.

Comment: what "hideContainerView" does ? can you post its code

Comment: i guess the issue is with you textview contraints..may be you are sibling the root view instead of the container